# In LLDB on MaxcOS why is it "the target has no associated executable images"

Tags: macos, lldb

I'm trying to use LLDB on MacOS to answer a simple post mortem question: on what line did my C program crash?

I haven't used LLDB much, so maybe I'm not doing this right.  Here's what I did. First I ran the program until it core dumped. Then

```
  lldb --core /cores/core.54068 ./linux_build/MCS  
(lldb) target create "./linux_build/MCS" --core "/cores/core.54068"
Core file '/cores/core.54068' (arm64) was loaded.
(lldb) target list
Current targets:
* target #0: <none> ( arch=arm64-apple-*, platform=host, state=stopped )
(lldb) source list
(lldb) f
frame #0: 0x0000000102d88610
->  0x102d88610: brk    #0x4
    0x102d88614: msub   w2, w24, w22, w23
    0x102d88618: mov    w0, w24
    0x102d8861c: stur   w2, [x5, #-0x34]
(lldb) l -
(lldb) target modules list
error: the target has no associated executable images
(lldb) exit
```

So it seems to me that LLDB doesn't know that the executable image is ./linux_build/MCS, even though this information was on the command line and so in the `target create` command that was automatically executed first.

One weird thing is that the executable is reported as x86_64.  I would have expected it to be for the ARM.

```
  file ./linux_build/MCS 
./linux_build/MCS: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

  gcc --version   
Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

The OS version is Ventura 13.4.1.  Here's some more version information

```
  lldb --version 
lldb-1403.0.17.67
Apple Swift version 5.8.1 (swiftlang-5.8.0.124.5 clang-1403.0.22.11.100)

  uname -a 
Darwin Russell-4 22.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 22.5.0: Thu Jun  8 22:22:20 PDT 2023; root:xnu-8796.121.3~7/RELEASE_ARM64_T6000 x86_64
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem does have to do with the fact that the program was compiled for x86_64, because when I recompiled with `-target arm64-apple-macos11 -mmacosx-version-min=11.0` the LLDB target did get set.  But I'll leave the question here since the same crash did not happen with the ARM executable. Now I wonder whether my code has a bug or Rosetta has a bug!

Comment: Rosetta processes are arm64 processes and similarly core files from a Rosetta process are arm64 core files.  Debugging a Rosetta process when it is running requires a special debug agent that cooperates with the Rosetta runtime to do the backwards mapping from executing arm64 code to the original x86_64 code.  You have the same need in order to map the arm64 code whose execution was recorded in your core file back to the original x86_64 binary, but to my knowledge no-one has built a tool to do that mapping.  So all you see is the arm64 side.

Comment: You'd really need to see if the x86_64 build of you app crashed in the same way when running natively, to know whether this was your or Rosetta's bug.

Comment: Luckily the crash behaviour was reproducible, so, based on @JimIngham 's first comment, the approach that worked to answer the question of where the code crashed was to ignore the core file and run `lldb my-x86-executable` and then use the lldb `run` command.  CRASH.  Line identified. Done.